# Sybase SQL Anywhere 17 - Can a database trigger call a system command?

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere

I have a Sybase SQL Anywhere 17 server running on Linux, and I was wondering if it is possible to create a database trigger to execute a local operating system system command when an UPDATE is down on a particular database record?
Essentially, if a database table.field is updated to "complete",  execute /usr/local/bin/notify

I have done this previously with other database systems, but looking over the SQLAW17 documentation, I can't find any references on how to do this (the trigger documentation seems to refer to stored procedures etc, not clear if I can or should do this as a stored procedure, etc).

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, trigger is essentially a stored procedure. It just created with `create trigger` instead of `create procedure`.

Inside the trigger (as well as inside any procedure), you can execute external tool with `xp_cmdshell`.

So, assuming you have a table `tbl` with two fields `name` and `status` you can have something like:

```
create trigger on_complete after update on tbl 
begin
   declare msg text;
   declare cmd text;

   if new.status = "completed" then
      set msg = "Completed " || new.name
      set cmd = '/usr/local/bin/notify "'||msg||'"';
      call xp_cmdshell(cmd, 'no_output' );
   end if
end;
```